# How to select JSON output into TableViewCell in Swift 3.0 ?

Tags: php, json, swift3, uitableview

If these **JSON** output

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "display": [{"refno":"1111", "dtfrom":"2017-12-12"},{"refno":"2222","dtfrom":"2017-12-15"}]
}
```

Can retrieve **"display"** output in **Swift 3.0 TableViewCell** like below code

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var movementstatus: [MovementStatus]? = []
    var detailsVC : MovementDetailsVC?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchMovement()
    }

    func fetchMovement() {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/get.json")!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data,response,error)in
            if error != nil {return}

            self.movementstatus = [MovementStatus]()
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                if let msFromJson = json["display"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
                    for mFromJson in msFromJson
                    {
                        let ms = MovementStatus()
                        if let dtfrom = mFromJson["dtfrom"] as? String, let refno  = mFromJson["refno"] as? String {
                            ms.dtfrom       = dtfrom
                            ms.refno        = refno
                        }
                        self.movementstatus?.append(ms)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch let error{ print(error)}
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "movementCell", for: indexPath) as! MovementStatusCell
        cell.dtfromLbl.text         = self.movementstatus?[indexPath.item].dtfrom
        cell.refnoLbl.text          = self.movementstatus?[indexPath.item].refno
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.movementstatus?.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (detailsVC == nil) {
            detailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovementDetails") as? MovementDetailsVC
        }
        detailsVC?.move = self.movementstatus?[indexPath.item]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVC!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

My question is how do i modify it if the JSON output look like this in TableViewCell above ?

**JSON output**

```
{"display":"1", "refno":"1111","dtfrom":"2017-12-15"}
{"display":"1", "refno":"2222","dtfrom":"2017-12-20"}
```

Because in PHP, I set the **"display"** as 1, 2, and 3 to produce an output.

**display.php**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");
    global $connect;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $refnodb     = $row['refno'];
                $dtfromdb    = $row['dtfrom'];

                $output= array('display' => '1', 'refno' => $refnodb, 'dtfrom' => $dtfromdb);
                echo json_encode($output);
                exit();
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            $output = array('display' => '2', 'refno' => 'value not found !');
            echo json_encode($output);
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
            exit();
        }
    }
    else {
        $output = array('message' => '3', 'refno' => 'No value post yet !');
        echo json_encode($output);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

My goal is to set **"display"** output as Integer in Swift 3.0. Normally I use code below to retrieve those JSON output and set it as Integer.

**test.swift**

```
import UIKit
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var valueLbl: UITextField!
    var value: String!    
    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()}

    @IBAction func sendData(_ sender: Any) {
        value = valueLbl.text
        let url     = URL(string: "http://localhost/get.php")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let DataToPost = "submit=\(value!)"
        request.httpBody = DataToPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { return }
            else {
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String] {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let display     = Int(json["display"]!)
                                let refno       = json["refno"]
                                let dtfrom      = json["dtfrom"]

                                if(display == 1) {
                                    return
                                }
                                else if(display == 2) {
                                    return
                                }
                                else if(display == 3) {
                                    return
                                }
                        }  
                    }  
                }
                catch {}
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

But in TableViewCell, I don't know how to use it. Appreciate if someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: The second one will give you single object, not multiple means at a time your JSON response is only `{"display":"1", "refno":"1111","dtfrom":"2017-12-15"}`. Not two response. Right?

Comment: yup. it only display one value at a time only

Comment: You want to show this single record in `tableView` ?, Also are you able to get value in `display` with line `let display     = Int(json["display"]!)` ?

Comment: Nope. I can't get the value of display if the JSON output like the number two. It only work when JSON output is like the number one

Comment: Try to print the just `json` Dictionary and check are you getting value with it.

Comment: Are you getting the console log for `json` dictionary or not?

Comment: error "data is outside a range" . I am not sure what i'm missing here

Comment: Where you are getting this error?

Comment: inside 'if let msFromJson'

Comment: But you have told that first one is perfectly working.

Comment: if the json output like the top. But it does not work if the json ouput is like the second

Comment: It obvious because in second response you are having dictionary as root response not array as root response.

Comment: I see. Thats mean in PHP code I need to display JSON output like the top one ?

Comment: No, that not i'm saying, you can still handle the response in ios app side also. Using `if let` or `guard let`.

Comment: I see . I will take note on that . . Thanks . .

Comment: Should I post this as solution would you care to accept it?

Comment: Where to accept the answer ?

Comment: Haven't posted yet, I'm asking you, If i post my comment solution as answer  would you accept the answer then?

Comment: yup. your answer is the solution . proceed

Comment: I have posted answer if it works for you then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your JSON response is `Dictionary` or `Array` type using `if let`

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) 
    if let array = json as? [[String:Any]] {
        //response is array
    }
    if let dictionary = json as? [String:Any] {
        if let display = dictionary["display"] as? String,
           let refno = dictionary["refno"] as? String,
           let dtfrom = dictionary["dtfrom"] as? String {

            print(display)
            print(refno)
            print(dtfrom)
        }
    }
} 
catch {}
```

Comment: @Jamilah Ok will wait for your response :)

Comment: cannot run the code . I try like this but it didnt work .              do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as AnyObject
                if let array = json as? [[String:Any]] {
                    let movement = Int(json["movement"]!)
                    
                    if(movement == 1) {
                    
                        print("test")
                        return
                    }
                
                    print(array)
                }
            } 
            catch {}

Comment: @Jamilah Why you are trying to convert it to anyObject, Don't do that and what is `movement` there is nothing like `movement` in your response. Also you are using json not array or dictionary like my solution.

Comment: opps. sorry . I mean "display"

Comment: Can you add example in your // response is array part so I can try it in my code

Comment: @Jamilah Can you show that response so that I can edit my answer according to it.

Comment: Only dictionary can be print out "Dictionary :["display":"1", "refno":"1111","dtfrom":"2017-12-15"]" . Array does not print any value

Comment: @Jamilah It is obvious if your top level JSON response is Dictionary then it will go in Dictionary part, if your top level JSON response is Array it will go in array part.

Comment: yup. i can select json "display" only by using this "let ms = dictionary["display"]
print("ms : \(ms!)")"

Comment: But how to set the display it as Int type ? cause I want to make if statement inside the dictionary

Comment: @Jamilah Check the edited answer. inside the Dictionary block

Comment: So far no error appear . as I created like this                         if(displayInt == 1){
                            
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            return
                        } . Appreciate if you can show how to display the json data inside that statement

Comment: I mean this json output "{"display":"1", "refno":"1111","dtfrom":"2017-12-15"}"

Comment: it does not print any value . I mean print(displayInt)

Comment: @Jamilah Check the edited answer and check it is printing anything in console reply here the console log.

Comment: yup. value "1" appear on console . but how to display the rest of JSON output {"display":"1", "refno":"1111","dtfrom":"2017-12-15"}

Comment: I declare the type display as Int like this                         let finalDis = Int(display)
                        if(finalDis == 1){
                            return
                        }
                        print(display) . I want to display refno and dtfrom inside that if block statement

Comment: @Jamilah Check the edited answer for that. Not that if you add return before the print statement it will not display in console log.

Comment: One more question. Is this dictionary work with multiple object data ? i.e  {"display":"1"}{"display":"1"}{"display":"1"} did it display 3 times or only one executed ? . .

Comment: @Jamilah In that case all this dictionary should be inside array without it not possible.

Comment: I see .  Thanks . god bless you . :)

Comment: @Jamilah Welcome mate :)